# DNS nslookup query not returning all the Name Servers

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have 4 DNS servers which are across two datacenters. They are also the domain servers.

When I query nslookup test.com.au, it's only returning one of the DNS servers, the other 3 servers are not listed. Any idea why?
I don't think its normal behavior as the nslookup suppose to return all the name servers.

Below is the result which returns only one DNS server 10.208.240.20

```
Server:  localhost
Address:  127.0.0.1

Name:    test.com.au
Address:  10.208.240.20
```

Below is the result of NS server query.

```
test.com.au nameserver = dc10.test.com.au

test.com.au nameserver = dc11.test.com.au

test.com.au nameserver = dc09.test.com.au

test.com.au nameserver = dc12.test.com.au

dc10.test.com.au    internet address = 10.208.244.10

dc11.test.com.au    internet address = 10.208.240.20

dc09.test.com.au    internet address = 10.208.240.10

dc12.test.com.au    internet address = 10.208.244.20
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem here. The first two lines of nslookup are the forward and reverse records of the nameserver that nslookup is connected to. The remaining lines are the answer to the question you asked.

NSLOOKUP from a domain with 2 DC's:

```
C:\>nslookup -type=NS acme.com
Server:  dc11.acme.com
Address:  10.11.12.13

acme.com   nameserver = dc11.acme.com
acme.com   nameserver = dc12.acme.com
dc11.acme.com internet address = 10.11.12.13
dc12.acme.com internet address = 10.12.13.14
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I expect the command "nslookup test.com.au" to return all four NS addresses, instead of one. I build 3 other identical domain/DNS environments. Only this test.com.au DNS environment is returning single NS record.

Comment: What was your exact CLI invocation and the output? You can edit the original post. What you posted so far appears to have been edited.